# Powershell - Delete all lines in a CSV up to and including a specific string for all files in a folder.

Tags: csv, powershell, scripting

I have the following code which searches for a string in a file and returns the line number to a variable. It then deletes all lines up to and including this line. I need to modify this code to run for all .CSV files in a directory.

```
$a = Select-String draft.csv -Pattern RESULTS -CaseSensitive | Select -expand LineNumber
$content = Get-Content draft.csv
$content | Foreach {$n=1} {if ($n++ -ge ($a+1)) {$_}} > draft.csv
```

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Show some effort and post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added the code snippet to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this task using the following. If anyone has a faster method, I'm glad to hear it.

```
ForEach ($file in Get-ChildItem *.csv)
{
    $filename = $file.fullname

    $a = Select-String $filename -Pattern RESULTS -CaseSensitive | Select -expand LineNumber
    $content = Get-Content $filename
    $content | Foreach {$n=1} {if ($n++ -ge ($a+1)) {$_}} > $filename
    Echo $filename "is Complete.... Moving On!"

}
```